# Для чего контекст и аргументы приравнивают к null?

Tags: javascript, функции, settimeout, декоратор

Напишите функцию throttle(f, ms) – «тормозилку», которая возвращает обёртку, передающую вызов f не чаще, чем раз в ms миллисекунд

Визуально это даст следующую картину обработки перемещений мыши:

1. Первое обновление произойдёт сразу (это важно, посетитель тут же видит реакцию на своё действие).
2. Дальше может быть много вызовов (микро-передвижений) с разными координатами, но пока не пройдёт 100 мс – ничего не будет.
3. По истечении 100 мс – опять обновление, с последними координатами. Промежуточные микро-передвижения игнорированы.
4. В конце концов мышь где-то остановится, обновление по окончании очередной паузы 100 мс сработает с последними координатами.

   ```
   function throttle(func, ms) {

     var isThrottled = false,
       savedArgs,
       savedThis;

     function wrapper() {

       if (isThrottled) { // (2)
         savedArgs = arguments;
         savedThis = this;
         return;
       }

       func.apply(this, arguments); // (1)

       isThrottled = true;

       setTimeout(function() {
         isThrottled = false; // (3)
         if (savedArgs) {
           wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
           savedArgs = savedThis = null;
         }
       }, ms);
     }

     return wrapper;
   }
   ```

Шаги работы этой функции:

1. Декоратор throttle возвращает функцию-обёртку wrapper, которая при первом вызове запускает func и переходит в состояние «паузы» (isThrottled = true).
2. В этом состоянии все новые вызовы запоминаются в замыкании через savedArgs/savedThis. Обратим внимание, что и контекст вызова и аргументы для нас одинаково важны и запоминаются одновременно. Только зная и то и другое, можно воспроизвести вызов правильно.
3. Далее, когда пройдёт таймаут ms миллисекунд – пауза будет снята, а wrapper – запущен с последними аргументами и контекстом (если во время паузы были вызовы).

Шаг (3) запускает именно не саму функцию, а снова wrapper, так как необходимо не только выполнить func, но и снова поставить выполнение на паузу. Получается последовательность «вызов – пауза… вызов – пауза … вызов – пауза …», каждое выполнение в обязательном порядке сопровождается паузой после него. Это удобно описывается рекурсией.

У меня вопрос по строке `savedArgs = savedThis = null`. В данном случае контекст и  аргументы становятся пустыми, потому что был последний вызов и он сработал с последними аргументами. И что бы вновь поставить func  на паузу по сути приравнивают  аргументы и контекст к null?

Comment: нет, эту строку можно убрать и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: хотя нет, кое-что все-таки поменяется :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в `setTimeout` проверяется следующее условие:

```
if (savedArgs) {
    wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
    savedArgs = savedThis = null;
}
```

Таким образом идет определение - вызывалась ли функция за время *торможения* либо нет, и если вызывалась, то вызвать ее с последними аргументами.

После этого идет сбрасывание `savedArgs`, чтобы на следующем цикле, в случае, если не было вызовов - ничего не вызывать. Если убрать сбрасывание - будет бесконечный цикл с последними аргументами.

Присваивание `savedThis` - можно убрать, оно ни на что не влияет.

Примеры:

```js
function throttle(func, ms) {

  var isThrottled = false,
    savedArgs,
    savedThis;

  var counter = 0; // только чтобы избежать бесконечного цикла
  function wrapper() {

    if (isThrottled) { // (2)
      savedArgs = arguments;
      savedThis = this;
      return;
    }

    func.apply(this, arguments); // (1)

    isThrottled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      isThrottled = false; // (3)
      if (savedArgs && ++counter < 5) {
        wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
        //savedArgs = savedThis = null;

      }
    }, ms);
  }

  return wrapper;
}

var t = throttle(function(a) {
  console.log(a)
}, 200);

t(1);
t(2);
t(3);
t(4);
```

---

Так же можно было обойтись дополнительным флагом, показывающим были вызовы внутри интервала или нет

```js
function throttle(func, ms) {

  var isThrottled = false,
    savedArgs,
    savedThis,
    calledInThrottle = false;

  function wrapper() {

    if (isThrottled) { // (2)
      savedArgs = arguments;
      savedThis = this;
      calledInThrottle = true;
      return;
    }

    func.apply(this, arguments); // (1)

    isThrottled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      isThrottled = false; // (3)
      if (calledInThrottle) {
        calledInThrottle = false;
        wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
      }
    }, ms);
  }

  return wrapper;
}

var t = throttle(function(a) {
  console.log(a)
}, 200);

t(1);
t(2);
t(3);
t(4);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за  стольразвёрнутый ответ,да ещё и с другими интнресными вариациями! И вот ещё маленький такой вопрос:вот эта часть кода:                                if (isThrottled) { // (2)
      savedArgs = arguments;
      savedThis = this;
      return;как раз и отвечает за игнорирование промежуточных вызовов во время паузы вплоть до последнего когда, пройдёт 100мс?

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, да, `isThrottled` сбрасывается только в setTimeout, до этого момента он true, следовательно условие всегда выполняется, параметры сохраняются и происходит выход из функции

Comment: Ясно,спасибо вам большое!